# How to initialize columns in hybrid sparse tensor

Tags: pytorch, sparse-matrix

How initialize in pytorch hybrid tensor `torch.sparse_coo_tensor` (one dimension is sparse and other is not), which have the following dense representation?

```
array([[1, 0, 5, 0],
       [2, 0, 6, 0],
       [3, 0, 7, 0],
       [4, 0, 8, 0]])
```

What should I put into the `indices` argument?

Answer (score 1):

### How to initialize

Something like this:

```
import torch

indices = torch.tensor([[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3], [0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2]])
tensor = torch.sparse_coo_tensor(
    indices, torch.tensor([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]), size=(4, 4)
)
```

Given above:

- `indices` - first dimension specifies row, second column, where non-zero value(s) will be located. Those become pairs, in this case: `(0, 0)`, `(0, 2)`, `(1, 0)`, `(1, 2)`... and so on
- `values` - values located at those pairs, so `1` will be under `(0, 0)` coordinate, `2` under `(0, 2)` and so it goes.
- `size` - total size of the matrix, optional, might be inferred in this case from your input

**8 pairs, 8 values**, there are also other ways to specify it, but the idea holds.

And a quick check:

```
print(tensor)

print(tensor.to_dense())
```

Gives us:

```
tensor(indices=tensor([[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3],
                       [0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2]]),
       values=tensor([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]),
       size=(4, 4), nnz=8, layout=torch.sparse_coo)
tensor([[1, 0, 2, 0],
        [3, 0, 4, 0],
        [5, 0, 6, 0],
        [7, 0, 8, 0]])
```

### Why to initialize

**If your actual data is `50%` sparse, you shouldn't use COO tensor**.
It will save some memory, but operations will be way slower, so keep that in mind.

Comment: My matrix has only a few columns initialized. But if there is one value in a column, it means that all values in this column are non-zero. That's why I've talked about __hybrid__ Tensor. For example with the following indices, I can initialize the two rows, without specifying the second dimension `i = [[0,1]]
v = [np.array([1,2,3,4]),[5,6,7,8]]` . But your proposition about vanilla sparse tensors, not the hybrid ones.

Comment: @Cat-with-a-pipe there is no point in any sparsity in this case. Just save indices to non-zero columns, total number of columns and non-zero columns themselves. Return `0` if the data is not from the dense column. There is no "hybrid" tensor in PyTorch. Also, why do you need columns full of zeros? They bear no information whatsoever, are you absolutely sure you have to?

Comment: The pytorch documentation says, that there are hybrid tensors (https://pytorch.org/docs/master/sparse.html). But probably only the last dimensions can be dense, and the first dimensions should be sparse.